# MVC5 use model inside create view of another model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

i am doing a asp net MVC5 web application.
I have two model `FootballLeague` and `FootballTeam`.
I want to be able to create a FootballLeague and its teams in the same view.

My model is like:

```
public class FootballLeague{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<FootballTeam> teams {get; set;}
}
```

and add in the create.cshtml view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Teams)
</div>
```

I have in `Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\FootballTeam.cshtml`.

The problem is that the partial view is not shown. Am I missing anything?

There is another way to implement this?

Comment: Do you have any markup inside your EditorTemplate ?

Comment: Also How many Items you have in your `Teams` property  of your Main views view model ?

Comment: @Shyju I have no markups in my EditorTemplate and the number of Items varies depending on the FootballLeague.

Comment: Another way to implement this is to create 1 view model that will cater both your FootballTeam and FootballLeague together with a single view instead of rendering partial views. And using the same model you can use a single or two controllers to handle your post. Just an idea. If you want to push through with your idea try checking out this [tutorial](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2012/12/aspnet-mvc-display-and-editor-templates.html)

Comment: @Shyju following the tutorial I could show the partial view of the team but the collection is null in the controller create action. You know why is this happening?